# How do I remove a view?

Tags: views, 7

I installed [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) and created a few views. I decided that I want to begin anew with fresh settings, so I disabled Calendar and removed it. The undesired view disappeared. I extracted a fresh copy of Calendar to sites/all/modules and enabled it, but the old view appears again.

Do you know how to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules that are compatible with Views have default views; when you uninstall the module, the default views of that module are removed, but they re-appear when you install again the same module.
If you clone the default view of a module, and then uninstall that module, Views should show a warning about the module not being enabled, and not show the view in the list of views. Again, when you re-install that module, Views should show back the view you created.

Comment: I reinstalled all Drupal and now I'm using backups. Maybe it should helped to delete it directly from the database. I haven't tried if uninstall would help, but it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you customized a default view provided by the calendar module, you can revert it back to the default by clicking on "revert" (Click on the pointer behind edit).

Comment: There is not `revert` option, only `edit, enable, clone, export`

Comment: @xralf If there is no option to revert, then it's using the view as defined by the module.